# How can a simple string comparison cause an OleException?

Tags: c++, crash, ole

I have this piece of C++ code:

```
static CString timeout(_T("TIMEOUT"));
if(strError.Left(7).CompareNoCase(timeout) == 0) return TRUE;
```

In my immediate windows, I see following value for `strError`:

```
? strError
L""
ATL::CSimpleStringT<wchar_t,1>: L""
```

I'm getting following exception (I'm debugging a crash dump):

```
Unhandled exception at 0x74B4A9F2 in CRASH.DMP: Microsoft C++ exception: 
COleException at memory location 0x01BFFD14. occurred
```

My call stack is the following:

```
   KERNELBASE.dll!_RaiseException@16()  Unknown
   msvcr110.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 152  C++
   mfc110u.dll!AfxThrowOleException(long)   Unknown
   mfc110u.dll!ATL::AtlThrowImpl(long)  Unknown
   mfc110u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >::CompareNoCase(wchar_t const *)  Unknown
>  <Application>.exe!<Own_Class>::<Own_Function>(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > & strError) Line 106 C++
```

As I was having a crash while checking `.Left(7)` of an empty string, I immediately assumed this was the course of the issue. However I've realised that this piece of code generally is working fine (I just double-checked this), and while having a second look, I see that the exception if not an access violation or a nullpointerexception, but an Ole related exception. In the meanwhile I've understood that the issue's not within the `strError.Left(7)` part: it seems to be the `CompareNoCase()` method, going wrong, but how?

Can anybody enlighten me what's doing wrong in my code?

As far as `strError` is concerned, it gets created as follows:

```
CString strError;
...
strError = <function>();
```

where `<function>()` is something like:

```
CString <function>(){
...
  return _T("fix string"); // or:
  return <Complicated_function_handling>();
```

In this particular case, I have no idea how `strError` has been created (I know it's empty, as clearly seen in the immediate window, but I only have the crash dump, so I can read current values, but I don't know their history).

One thing, which might be helpful: I've asked for the memory address of `strError`, and I've looked at the data within memory (using Visual Studio Memory debug window), and I get following data:

```
5c 18 9c 71 38 d9 ca 00 03 00 00 00 cc 3d c2 00 70 fe bf 01 94 13 b3 00 39 00 00 00 80 fe bf 01 be 58 aa 00 b0 3d c2 00 10 0c cd 00 44 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 d3 5f ac 00 8a 40 1d 72 8e f2 d6 73
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you forming strError?

Comment: *"Can anybody enlighten me what's doing wrong in my code?"* You only posted two lines of code. They work fine for me if I add `CString strError(_T("test"));` and a `main` boilerplate. Please post a self-contained, runnable, minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Jangid: I'm sorry, but I'm debugging a crash dump here. I tried to follow how that empty string has been created, but I can't follow it back in the code. In which way can the forming of `strError` have an impact on this issue? I mean, it's just a value, isn't it?

Comment: If you look at `atlexcept.h`, you will see that `AtlThrowImpl` calls `AfxThrowOleException`.  Then this: `<Own_Class>::<Own_Function>` -- does this mean `Own_Function` is a non-static member function of a class?  If so, how do you check if `Own_Class` is a valid instance?  If `Own_Class` is not a valid instance, then any code that seems normal becomes "abnormal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working my thru the source for MFC, the exception is being thrown because `timeOut` is a NULL string.  Common ways that this can happen are if it has not been constructed yet, or it has been destroyed.  The error code stored within the `COleException` is `E_FAIL`.

The call sequence goes something like this:

- `CompareNoCase` calls `AtlIsValidString` (which will return false in your case if `timeOut`, when converted to a `const char *`, is NULL).
- Since `AtlIsValidString` returns false, the code associated with the `ATLENSURE` macro calls `AtlThrow(E_FAIL)` (`AtlThrow` is a macro that is defined as `ATL::AtlThrowImpl`.
- `AtlThrowImpl` calls `AfxThrowOleException` since the error code is not `E_OUTOFMEMORY`.

Comment: How can `timeout` be `NULL`? It has been created, just the line before: `static CString timeout(_T("TIMEOUT"));`. Can this be a multithreading race condition?

Comment: @Dominique Which version of MSVC are you using?  Before C++11 threading could be an issue; I don't know which version of MSVC added support for thread safe static locals.  If this crash happens during program exit, `timeout` could have been destroyed (and won't be recreated if someone tries to use it later).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm working with Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (according to Visual Studio, Help, About, first entry (`Visual C++ 2017   00370-20006-39830-AA117`)).