# How can a CPtrList->RemoveHead() cause an CInvalidArgumentException?

Tags: c++, mfc

This question is quite similar to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666981/how-can-a-simple-string-comparison-cause-an-oleexception), this time I'd like to get more acquainted with the subject, or at least with its documentation:

I'm dealing with a process crash, due to a `CInvalidArgException`, while performing a `RemoveHead()` of a `CPtrList` object, containing 6 entries.

The wrong piece of source looks as follows:

```
pSingle = (SET_PARAMETER*)plMultiple->RemoveHead();
```

The call stack is as follows:

```
mfc110u.dll!AfxThrowInvalidArgException(void)
mfc110u.dll!CObList::RemoveHead(void)
Application.exe!SingleThread(void * pArg=0x0000006800000000) Line 673
```

In order to understand what's happening, I'm having a look at [the official Microsoft documentation website about CPtrList(CObList) RemoveHead()](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/cpp/mfc/reference/coblist-class?view=vs-2017#removehead), but I don't find any reference towards a `CInvalidArgException`.

Just for a small comparison: for Java programmers, there's a documentation which explains every exception you might encounter while programming (e.g. [Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractInterruptibleChannel.html) mentions all exceptions, which might be thrown while executing a method).

I'd like to know if there is something similar for C++ (STL) programmers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the source code, which ships with the product?

Comment: Are you debugging a crash dump again as in the previous question you reference? That makes a difference.

Comment: Also not sure where you got the idea that Java documentation mentions all exceptions. Certainly it has good coverage of possible exceptions, but that's no basis for assuming that it mentions them all, in particular `NullPointerException` and `IllegalArgumentException` are not usually mentioned, as is the case with other `RuntimeException` derived types..

Comment: The name `mfc110u.dll` suggests you're debugging a release build. Try to debug a debug build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the source code for `CObList` we see that the first line is:

```
ENSURE_VALID(this);
```

This macro is defined as:

```
#define ENSURE_VALID(pOb)   ENSURE_VALID_THROW(pOb, ::AfxThrowInvalidArgException() )
```

Which is in turn defined as:

```
#define ENSURE_VALID_THROW(pOb, exception)  \
do { ASSERT_VALID(pOb); if (!(pOb)){exception;} } while (false)
```

In other words, it will cause an assertion in debug mode, and in release mode it will call `AfxThrowInvalidArgException` which is what you are seeing.

In short, `plMultiple` is null.

Comment: Then why does the debugger tell me the number of entries equals 6? Is it possible that my object is `NULL` indeed, but in memory there are some garbage characters, which make my debugger (or more my natvis handler) think there's a value there? This makes the whole debugging process very unreliable.

Comment: @Dominique Are you debugging a debug build of the executable? That would be a good start. If you are trying to debug a release build, the stack trace my be unreliable due to duplicate comdat folding. You should be able to literally double-click the `CObList::RemoveHead` in the call stack and it should take you to the offending statement.

Comment: ASSERT_VALID does more than check for NULL. Ends up also checking whether the address is valid. So, it might not just be NULL, but could be invalid memory from a pointer already deleted.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson, that path results in an assertion not an exception, so unless she continued the assertion failure without telling us, it can't be that. Bottom line is she needs to use the facilities of the debugger, preferably in a debug build.